# How to Access WLAN TSF Values

Tags: synchronization, timestamp, wifi

How do I access WLAN TSF timer? I have investgated Windows SDK WLANapi, but cout not find any fuction to access TSF values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value of the Timing Synchronization Function is not available on OS level. You can read it from transmitted Wi-Fi frames, though, by looking at the `radiotap.mactime` in the radiotap header of Wireshark.